# 301 redirects in magento not working

Tags: apache, magento, redirect, http-status-code-301

i just moved a site to magento and not all the urls remained the same.  I'm having trouble with 301s for the changes.

Fist of all I'm using a magento multisite setup and i have the following code running in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=website1code
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=website1code
SetEnvIf Host ^domain1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host www\.domain2\.net MAGE_RUN_CODE=website2code
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain2\.net MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2\.net MAGE_RUN_CODE=website2code
SetEnvIf Host ^domain2\.net MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Here's one example of a url that I'm trying to redirect:

```
old:  http://domain1.com/category
new:  http://domain1.com/v1/category
```

Here's what I've tried:

1) First i tried a adding a simple line to the .htaccess file:

```
redirect 301 /category http://domain1.com/v1/category
```

2) I've also tried using the built in url rewrite manager in the admin panel following the guide here

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/urlrewrite/index
```

and 
    http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/seo/how_to_work_with_magento_url_rewrite_rules

I've used the following settings in the admin panel:

```
type: custom
store: chose
id path: /category
request path: /category
target path: http://domain1.com/v1/category
redirect: 301
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong and suggest an alternative for either direct .htaccess edit, or within the admin area?

thanks

Comment: anyone have any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a 301 domain redirect to subdir from `.htaccess` on my last virtual host. Note that the domain whose folder this resides in is NOT the domain shown below (is actually the domain in my profile), so it is a subdirectory type of deal for other domain pointers.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ducatitech/(.*) http://www.ducatitech.com/$1 [R=301]
Redirect 301 /ducatitech http://www.ducatitech.com
```

Other than sharing the above with you, I haven't done any domain sharing with respect to magento multi-store installations.